# Safety of accessing QObject method from different QThread

Tags: c++, qthread, qobject

I am writing an application which uses one main application thread and a second thread (and there are no other threads foreseen).
The second thread is implemented as a “worker” which means that I do not extend QThread class but I move my worker object to a Thread.
We have made here a small example:

**File: myObject.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <worker.h>
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObject(){}
    void member1();
    void member2();
    Worker* _worker;
};
```

**File: myObject.cpp**

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
void MyObject::member1()
{
    qDebug() << "MyObject::member1()";
    QThread* _thread = new QThread;
    _worker = new Worker(this);
    _worker->moveToThread(_thread);
    _thread->start();
    _worker->work();
}
void MyObject::member2()
{
    qDebug() << "MyObject::member2()";
}
```

**File: worker.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
class MyObject;
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(MyObject* myObj) : _myObj(myObj) {}
    void work();
private:
    MyObject* _myObj;
};
```

**File: myworker.cpp**

```
#include <worker.h>
#include <myobject.h>
#include <QDebug>
void Worker::work()
{
    qDebug() << "Worker::work()";
    _myObj->member2();
}
```

**File main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <myobject.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyObject myObject;
    myObject.member1();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Is it safe to access directly `_myObj->member2();` from `Worker::work`?
If not should I replace this call by signal & slot mechanism? If I should... why exactly?

Comment: You should replace it with signal and slot.

Comment: I would really love to know why exactly... I have ready many contradicting articles on Qt threading....

Comment: Calling an object in different thread than yours is inherently dangerous. Is the method even thread safe? With QObjects there is an additional issue of sending signals and invoking slots. Does `member1` does that? If by the time you call the `member1()` the event loop in the thread is NOT running your app will crash or at least fail to send the signal. By connecting `QThread::started` and `QObject::whatever` you ensure that the method is invoked correctly in the running thread with running event loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to access directly _myObj->member2(); from Worker::work?

Most likely not. It would depend on the implementation but generally speaking calling methods across threads is rarely safe. To make it safe you would need to apply locks/mutexes to whatever is being accessed (directly and indirectly) from that method and ensure that everything you call from that method is also thread-safe. Thankfully Qt signal & slots abstract that away so you need not worry about that.

> If not should I replace this call by signal & slot mechanism?

You should in a following manner:

`QObject::connect(_thread, &QThread::started, _worker, &MyObject::work);`

Remove the direct call to `MyObject::work()`. Also consider:

`QObject::connect(_thread, &QThread::finished, _thread, &QThread::deleteLater);`

Note that `QObject::connect` **is thead-safe**. It can be called from whatever thread on any object in any thread at any time.

> If I should... why exactly?

Calling an object in different thread than yours is inherently dangerous. Is the method you call thread safe? With `QObjects` there is an additional issue of sending signals and invoking slots. Does `work()` do that? If by the time you call the `work()` the event loop in the thread is **NOT** running your app will crash or at least fail to send the signal. By connecting `QThread::started` and `MyObject::work` you ensure that the method is invoked correctly in the running thread and with running event loop in correct sequence.

For completeness without signals & slots you should do this to ensure it will work as expected:

```
if(_thread->isRunning())
    _worker->work();
```